assign Angular signal-based inputs dynamically
I'm encountering an issue when trying to update inputs on a component loaded into an Angular CDK overlay.
Here's my component:
TypeScript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: '..', 
  imports: [...], 
})
export class MyComponent {
  readonly myInput = input.required<MyInputInterface>(); 

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myInput()); 
  }
}

I'm using Object.assign(componentRef.instance, context) to pass data to the component when creating the overlay. However, I get an error stating that this.myInput is not a function.
The component works correctly when used with a parent component and regular input binding. When debugging, I can see that myInput does have a value within the overlay component.
Could Object.assign be causing problems with the input setter or Angular's change detection within the overlay?

yes. obviously it brakes everything as it most likely places value in place of signal. use iteration over context and componentRef.setInput to set inputs values
